# Slicing a tensor with a dimension varying

Tags: pytorch, slice, tensor, torchscript

I'm trying to slice a PyTorch tensor `my_tensor` of dimensions `s x b x c` so that the slicing along the first dimension varies according to a tensor `indices` of length `b`, to the effect of:

`my_tensor[0:indices, torch.arange(0, b, dtype=torch.long), :] = something`

The code above doesn't work and receives the error `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`.

What I'm aiming for is, for example, if `indices = torch.tensor([3, 5, 4])` then:

`my_tensor[0:3, 0, :] = something`

`my_tensor[0:5, 1, :] = something`

`my_tensor[0:4, 2, :] = something`

I'm hoping for a tensorized way to do this so I don't have to resort to a for loop. *Also, the method needs to be compatible with TorchScript*. Thanks very much.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.